# how to preview a date - 60 days in a specific date format in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to preview a date before 60 days of a specific date in this date format: 03-Mar-2013 .. how can I subtract 60 days from this date ... I used this code but it didn't work as it subtract from the days only and it didn't subtract from the month or the year:

```
Select LTRIM(DAY(@date - 60))+'-'+CONVERT(varchar(3), DATENAME(MONTH,@date))+'-'+LTRIM(YEAR(@date))
```

Any help ?

Comment: Probably easiest to convert to date format, use the built in functions to subtract dates and then convert back (if needed).

Comment: @Gidil , which built in function ?!

Comment: Look at the answers already given. (DateAdd)

Comment: Try, if ever possible, toi avoid culture specific formats. The worst possible formats are those where parts of the string are bound to a language (like `Mar` in this case). If your code will ever run on a non-english server, you'll get into troubles...

Comment: If at all possible, don't store dates or datetimes in a `(N)VARCHAR` field. Use the appropriate type for that: `DATE`, `DATETIME` or `DATETIME2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this-

```
select REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), DATEADD(dd, -60, cast('03-Mar-2013' as date)), 106), ' ', '-') AS [DD-Mon-YYYY]
```

Comment: don't have enough reputation to check as it is the right answer :$

Comment: @BishoyEzzat, you might not have enough reputation to **vote**, but you are allowed to **accept** an answer to your own question. Voting and Acceptance are two different actions here. And btw: I'll push you over the magic 15 now, so you are allowed to vote **and** to accept, which is even better :-)

Comment: @James, your answer still has one draw back. This part `DATEADD(dd, -60, '03-Mar-2013')` will use an implicit conversion and is culture specific. Try it again and put `SET LANGUAGE GERMAN;` before your statement.

Comment: @Shnugo Thanks Dear :)

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
Select DateAdd(DD,-60,cast('03-Mar-2013' as date))
```

Returns

```
2013-01-02
```

To Formatt

```
Select Replace(Convert(varchar(11),DateAdd(DD,-60,cast('03-Mar-2013' as date)),106),' ','-')
```

Returns

```
02-Jan-2013
```

Comment: Hi, voted this...  This `cast('03-Mar-2013' as date)` is relying on the system's culture too...

Comment: @Shnugo Agreed - I made an assumption.    "Thanks Dear :)"

Comment: Yeah, I like friendly people ;-)